# What is the indefinite sum of tan(x)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, finite-differences

What is the indefinite sum of the tangent function, that is, the function $T$ for which

$\Delta_x T = T(x + 1) - T(x) = \tan(x)$

Of course, there are infinitely many answers, who all differ by a function of period 1. Ideally, I would like the solution to be of the form

$T(x) = $ nice_function$(x)$ + possibly_ugly_periodic_function$(x)$,
where nice is at least piece-wise continuous.

If any of the following sums can be found, the sum of tan can also be found:

- $\sum \sec x$
- $\sum \csc x$
- $\sum \cot x$
- $\sum \frac{1}{e^{ix} + 1}$

I have tried several methods without success, including using a newton series (which does not converge for non-integer $x$), and trying to guess possible functions.

I would also appreciate lines of attack if a solution is not known.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I add more details for the solution in the distinguished answer due to Anixx.  First, we need the **digamma** function
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function
which we will call $\Psi(x)$.  Important properties (from that web page) are: $\Psi(x)$ is analytic in the complex plane except at the nonpositive integers where it has simple poles.  $\Psi(x+1)-\Psi(x) = 1/x$.  $\Psi(x) > 0$ for $x>2$.  Asymptotics:
$$
  \Psi(x) = \log x - \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} + \frac{1}{120x^4} + O(x^{-6})
\qquad\text{as } x \to \infty .
$$
So, define $T(z) ={}$
$$
  -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \Biggl[\Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) - z + 1\Biggr) + \Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + z\Biggr) - \Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + 1\Biggr) - 
\Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr)\Biggr)\Biggr]
$$
For any fixed $z$, only finitely many preliminary terms involve $\Psi$ evaluated at a nonpositive argument, and the asymptotics of the remaining terms are computed (from the asymptotics given above) as
$$
\Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) - z + 1\Biggr) + \Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + z\Biggr) - \Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + 1\Biggr) - 
\Psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr)\Biggr)
$$

$=z(1-z)/(k^2\pi^2) + o(k^{-2})$ as $k \to \infty$.  So the series converges absolutely except when we are at a pole of one of the preliminary terms.  Now, because of absolute convergence, we may subtract term-by-term and simplify to get

$$
T(z+1)-T(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\Biggl[\frac{8z}{(-\pi+2\pi k-2z)(-\pi+2\pi k+2z)}\Biggr] = \tan z .
$$

Comment: NICE! I have to confess it only became obvious to me only after you wrote the thing out in full. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the additional information. Interestingly, it looks like $T(x + \pi) - T(x)$ is also periodic, with period 1.

Comment: Indeed, it is easy to prove that $T(z + \pi) - T(z) = -[\Psi(1 - (\pi/2 + z)) -\Psi(\pi/2 + z)] = -\pi \cot \pi(\pi/2 + z)$.

Comment: Alternatively: note that if you translate by any integer multiple of $\pi$ then you get another solution $T(z+m\pi)$ of the original problem.  So the difference between $T(z)$ and this other solution is periodic with period 1.

Comment: The book of N. E. Nörlund: Vorlesungen über Differenzenrechnung, 1923, reprinted by Chelsea, 1954 credites A. Hurwitz with showing, that a meromorphic sum can be found for any meromorphic right hand side in chapter 3, §1 historical remarks, 18. The work of Hurwitz is cited as "Sur l'integrale finie d'une fonction entiere", Acta math. 20 (1897), p. 285 - 312 and Acta math. 22 (1899), p. 197 - 180.

Answer (score 16):

And here is the plot of indefinite sum of tan(x):

[image]

Here you can see tan(x) in red and its indefinite sum is in blue.

As you can see, the indefinite sum is fairly continuous. Oleg Eroshkin's conclusion that this function should be discontinuous everywhere apparently came from a false assumption that indefinite sum of a periodic function should also be periodic.

Though it is true that as $|x|$ grows the density of the poles grows, showing the same behavior as in function $f(x)=\tan(x^2)$

The function shown on this plot is

$$T(z)=-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+1-z\right)+\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+z\right)-\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+1\right)-\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)+C$$

It can be derived from the first formula on [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/06/05/):

$$\tan(x)=8x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2k-1)^2\pi^2-4x^2}$$

We notice that there is a difference of squares in the denominator and separate the terms so to obtain

$$\tan(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{x-\pi k+\frac{\pi}2}+\frac1{x+\pi k-\frac{\pi}2}\right)$$

Now we take indefinite sum by each term to obtain the expression for T(x). All simple.

Comment: What is the blue plot of? How did you evaluate the $q$-function?

Comment: Am I reading the graph right? The blue graph ($T$) cuts the $x$-axis near (just before) 3, and near (just before) 4, $T$ is very large. But just before 3, $\tan x$ is close to 0. Can this be? $T(x+1)−T(x) = LARGE - 0 \neq SMALL = \tan x$ where x is just below 3. (Sorry, I know this is clumsy and inaccurate, but I hope you get my point).

Comment: Oh yes, there was an error on the graph, thank you for pointing it out. I've corrected.

Comment: I have made the periodic assumption you speak of (and of all the possible solutions, does this not hold for 1 of them?) to obtain a plot of certain points (several thousand) in the interval $[0, 1)$ In this case the function can have any value in any interval, however small (if I reason correctly). My initial hope was that we could add a periodic function (period 1) to this and get something like your blue function.

Comment: I have added the derivation.

Comment: But the plot was made from a partial sum of the series, I guess? Does the series converge somewhere?

Comment: "does this not hold for 1 of them?" No, it cannot because the period of tangent is not rational.

Comment: @Anixx, could you provide the details of the proof of convergence? What is the $\psi$ function?

Comment: It is digamma function. 

Comment: To be automatically CWified, the post has to be edited 8 times by you: you have edited it only four times (and no one else had edited it; the details are explained at http://mathoverflow.net/faq#communitywiki) I would not worry about that (yet :) )

Comment: Technically I normalized it for T(0)=0 after all iterations I made, but actually it will give the same result.

Comment: So far, this answer is more useful than the other one, so I will accept it (even though it is not immediately clear that it will converge, it is something that we can work with). 

Comment: Anixx, you might as well put a third answer with **full** details on exactly what series you are summing, where it converges and why. Meanwhile you might email Herman, using your pseudonym and a separate pseudonymous email account if you like, he is pretty happy and you have much in common. For Mariano, Gerald, Oleg and "J.M." the discussion of convergence of the **series** is far more interesting, most especially (as you have edited at least once) precisely what the series might be. Meanwhile, as long as Herman accepts one of your answers the relationship between you two is good. 

Comment: I think he accepts the answers not out of "good relations" but because they are more useful and/or correct. On the other hand seeing as people vote for apparently incorrect answer while refusing to vote for this one is certainly disappointing.

Comment: @Anixx, how can we tell if this is correct or not if we don't even know if the formula you wrote defines a function? Writing down a series does not automatically define a function...

Comment: I agree that Herman votes on the usefulness of the answer. I hope you don't refuse to write to Herman just because it is my idea. This particular question has been banging around for long enough, I do not expect many more votes for anything. I know from a friend (Wadim Zudilin) that getting insufficient votes makes people upset, especially an apparently wrong answer being upvoted and one's own answer not, or even downvoted. He quit MO for months over this issue. A third answer allows no CW while giving space for a full exposition. Again, I hope you don't refuse just because it is my idea. 

Comment: Close!  I get instead by this method

$$
T(z) :=
-\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) - z + 1\Biggr) + \psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + z\Biggr) - \psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) + 1\Biggr) -\psi \Biggl(\pi \biggl(k - \frac{1}{2}\biggr)\Biggr)
$$

The term is asymptotic to $z(1-z)/(k^2\pi^2)$ so we have absolute convergence, and the difference is as claimed.  Now, I suppose, the only quibble left is whether to consider this "closed form" or not.


Comment: Gerald, could you please write this at greater length as an answer, with details and estimates and anthing else useful. If you prefer, make it Community Wiki, I understand there is an icon to click as you post an answer. I have been looking up $\psi(z)$ in Abramowitz and Stegun,  but I got nowhere proving either convergence or lack of it anywhere except $z = 0,1.$ Will.

Comment: Even if the density of the poles grows, T(n+1)=T(n)+tan(n) is still always defined on the integers and appears to be almost periodic on the integers. T(n) is plotted in my answer below. 

Comment: @ Gerald, yes, when Herald pointed me to the mistake I only corrected the plot and forgot to correct the formula. Now corrected completely. Thank you for analyzing the convergence.

Comment: Gerald, in particular I don't understand how your asymptotic term
$ z ( 1-z) / (k^2 \pi^2)$ illustrates the apparent poles in the final function (blue curves).

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to think there is any simple expression for solution $T$ of
$$T(x + 1) - T(x) = \tan(x)$$

What we CAN find a simple solution to is this:
$$T(x + \pi) - T(x) = \tan(x)$$

Comment: Thank you. I know the solution to $T(x + \pi) - T(x)$, but I am hoping for a solution to the $T(x+1) - T(x)$ case. But if there is no "simple" solution, what avenues can I explore to get some sort of solution? 

Comment: It depends what you mean by a solution - do you want asymptotics, for instance? Fast numerical algorithms?

Answer (score 6):

There are no "nice" functions with such properties. Every solution is discontinuous at a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Just look on poles of $\tan x$. Let $x=\pi/2+\pi m$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly either $T$ is discontinuous at $x$ or at $x+1$. In the latter case it is also discontinuous at $x+k$ for every positive integer $k$. In the former case, $T$ is discontinuous at $x+k$ for every non-positive integer $k$.

Comment: It's interesting that a simple setup can lead to a complicated function like this. Thanks for your answer. (I am still interested if this is somehow a studied function).

Comment: For all those who voted for this answer, please notice that there is a counter-example to Eroshkin's claims. Such functions exists, mostly continuous and its plot is shown. See the currently selected answer.

Comment: Hrm Gerald's explanation looks pretty convincing, so let's sort out what the error is here... Is it just that "dense subset if the reals" doesn't actually follow from the conclusion? Instead what happens is that if m is positive then we have the "former" case while if m is negative we have the "latter" case. Thus the poles get more common as x increases but is always discrete for any any given interval.

Comment: Oleg's argument would only work if there were more "mixing" of the two cases. For example, if the former case happened for infinitely many negative numbers then the argument would go through. But as long as all sufficiently negative numbers are in the latter case and all sufficiently positive ones are in the former case, then there's a hole in the argument.

Comment: Oleg's argument's claims are fairly correct until the final conclusion. He correctly noted that the function should have poles at x+1+k or x-k for any natural k. The key word here is "either". The continuous sum function can be arranged so that for any pole right of zero all consecutive poles would be in x+1+k points, so to the right of the first one and for each pole in the left of zero all poles would be in the points x-k, so to the left of it.  Thus in the neighbourhood of zero itself the number of poles is limited.

Comment: Besides this is is from general considerations evident that for any continuous analytic function on the interval from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ can be constructed an indefinite sum function, continuous and analytic on the same interval plus a unit range. 

Comment: I agree with Anixx: the function can be made sort of nice in that it's piecewise continuous, the set of the places of discontinuitites is discrete and has no accumulation point, though these discontinuities get closer and closer to each other as you go to infinity.  You do this by choosing the function on the interval [0, 1) as an arbitrary continuous function, say all zeros, then extend the only possible way.

Answer (score 6):

Well I found the answer to your question, it is

$$\sum_x \tan(x)=ix-\psi _{e^{2 i}}^{(0)}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+C$$

I have verified it with difference operator and it gives tan(x). The function involved is the q-digamma function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html .

You can [verify the result yourself](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DifferenceDelta%28ix-qpolygamma%280,x%2bPi/2,e%5E%282i%29%29,x%29).

Comment: Is the q-polygamma well-defined at $q=e^{2i}$?

Comment: @Mariano: of course not.  The series (2) that "defines" it diverges for almost all real $x$


Comment: And the $q$-Pochammer symbol $(a,q)_\infty$ with $q=e^{2i}$ in the definition (1) also diverges for almost all $a$.

Comment: Gerald, you are confusing the infinite sum with sum over infinite range. There is no infinite series here.

Comment: I have always confused an infinite sum with a sum over an infinite range. How may I deconfuse the two?

Comment: Maybe by absence of the sign of infinity? And also this is clearly stated in the question caption.

Comment: By the way:  ask Wolfram Alpha to plot the function $ix-\psi _{e^{2 i}}^{(0)}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ or to numerically evaluate it for some real number $x$.

Comment: @Anixx: See (1) and (2) in the Mathworld page mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html Note that (2) involves an INFINITE series, and (1) -- if you follow the link involved -- involves an INFINITE product. Both of these are DIVERGENT for almost all real x in the case of $e^{2i}$.

Comment: @  Gerald Edgar

This function has wider domain of definition than the real axis and the values on the real axis may be can be assumed using limit technique. Even if not, then this is a solution for the complex plane except real axis.

Comment: @Anixx, I don't know what you mean by "the question caption." I see no infinite sum anywhere in the question, nor any sum over an infinite range (although I see several sums over an unspecified range), so I regret to say that pointing to the question has not helped me to deconfuse the two kinds of sum. Please be patient with me and try again. Thanks. 

Comment: @Anixx Very interesting, thank you! How did you discover this?

Comment: Note that $\psi_q(x)$ is defined only if $|q|<1$, which fails for $q=e^{2i}$.  The series (or product) involved diverges even for complex $x$.


Comment: @ Gerald Edgar, on this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html they use q-polygamma with |q|=e are they wrong?

Also Mathematica evaluates q-polygamma with |q|>1 quite well.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/QPolyGamma.html



Comment: Now do $q$-Polygamma with $q=e^{2i}$, which is needed here! For example:

QPolyGamma[0.1234,Exp[2*I]] // N


Comment: Yes, it is not supported by Mathematica. This does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: @Anixx: But, so far, it has no known definition.  So should we cite it as the solution to a problem?



Comment: Gerald Edgar, I did best of what I could. I think this is the most close answer to the question. 

Comment: See my new answer with the plot of this function.

Comment: If you're trying to subtract two divergent quantities to get a meaningful answer, shouldn't you be trying to figure out first why exactly those divergences cancel out?

Comment: QUESTION:  Is there some sense in which Anixx's other solution, the one I liked, can be interpreted as $ix-\psi _{e^{2 i}}^{(0)}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ ??


Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/06/02/0001/

Comment: Also, Annix, could you please give the link to the indefinite product of $\tan x$ you had here somewhere again? There is a nice relationship between $\int T(x)$ and $\prod \tan x$ which I wish to investigate.

Comment: @Gerald, I hope it can, especially since more generally $\sum \frac{a}{1-q^x} = a\frac{\psi_{q}(x)}{\ln q} - ax$ whenever everything is nicely defined. With $a = i$ and $q = e^{2i}$, we get the $\tan$ (translated) case.

Comment: @Herman Tulleken

Here is it:

$$\prod _x \tan(x) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} i (-2 x+\pi +2) x} \left(-1;e^i\right){}_x \left(e^i;e^i\right){}_{x-1}}{\left(-1;e^{-2 i}\right){}_x}$$

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite integral of tan(x) is -ln |cos(x)|, so find out how that expression was arrived at and see if this can be adpated to the discrete case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_integrals#Trigonometric_functions

Or go for an approximate answer: truncate the taylor series and find the indefinite sum of that polynomial. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
tan(x) = x+x^3/3+...  and sum(x+x^3/3,x) = (7/12)x^2-(1/2)x+(1/12)x^4-(1/6)x^3

The problem with this is tan(x) is periodically discontinuous and the taylor series is only valid for one period.

Comment: The indefinite integral (typically) requires the use of substitution, which exists because of the "nice" chain rule for differentiation. Differencing does not have a nice chain rule (there are some variants, but they do not help in this case).

I'll play with truncated Taylor series and see where it gets me (I guess I should have tried that already).

Comment: Ok, a few quick tests in Matlab shows that even in the range $[0 \pi/2]$ that the indefinite sum of Taylor series does not converge. In light of what Oleg Eroshkin said below, this makes sense, so this method cannot be used for finding an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in Jolley's Summation Of Series, which is pretty close to saying it doesn't exist. Have you tried Euler-Maclaurin summation to get an asymptotic series?

Answer (score 2):

Consider T(x) in T(x+1)-T(x)=tan(x) to be defined only on the integers>=0 and write it as the recurrence relation :

T(n+1)-T(n)=tan(n) 
and set the initial value at T(0)=0,

and then without needing a closed form expression for T(n) in terms of n,

but just plotting the values of T(n+1)=T(n)+tan(n)

we can see what the function looks like when restricted to the integers:

[image: Image of plot of T(n+1)=T(n)+tan(n), T(0)=0]

The top-left image shows the function plotted from n=..750

The left column of images is the plot, the middle images join the dots to get a look at the shape, and the right column shows were the image is zoomed to get the images on the next row.

The function T(n) appears to be almost periodic with period about 355.5

T(n) maximum is about 3.5, T min is about -425.

Comment: The observed almost periodicity with period about 355 should relate to the fact that pi = 355/113, so that tan(x + 355) ~= tan(x + 113pi) = tan x.  Note, though, that this the approximation above is only good when x + 355 and x + 113pi are not close to multiples of pi.

If you were to look at this function on a larger scale you'd probably also see something like almost periodicity with longer periods corresponding to better rational approximations of pi (although 355/113 is exceptionally close to pi, so you'dhave to zoom out a lot to get a better one, and it might be less impressive.)

Comment: (er, make that "when x + 355 and x + 113 pi are not close to odd multiples of pi/2, that is, the points of discontinuity of tan x").

Answer (score 1):

The Maple command for indefinite sums (as described on the page http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=sum/details, found via Google by typing "indefinite sum" maple) is given by

sum(f,x);

I tried this, but my version of Maple doesn't know the answer when f=tan(x).

For sin(x) it gives sum(sin(x),x);= -(1/2)sin(x)+(1/2)*sin(1)cos(x)/(cos(1)-1)

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure if there is a simple expression, it is not an elementary function, which is why these symbolic programs don't know it. But it might still be a studied special function...