# Are these two functions equal?

Tags: difference-equations, finite-differences, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The question here is sparked by the discussion inside [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41011/what-is-the-indefinite-sum-of-tanx/42903#42903) about indefinite sum(antidifference) of tan(x).

A proposed solution was a function 
$$f_1(x)=ix-\psi _{e^{2 i}}^{(0)}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+C$$
The function involved is the [q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). Symbolically it resolves to be antidifference of tan(x), one can check it by following this link to [Wolfran Alpha's result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DifferenceDelta%28ix-qpolygamma%280,x%2bPi/2,e%5E%282i%29%29,x%29).

But it turned out that neither Wolfram Alpha, nor any other software is able to evaluate the q-polygamma function with $q=e^{2 i}$ numerically. Attempting to evaluate it manually also turned out to be too difficult.

A second solution seemed to be easier to evaluate. It was a series that converged absolutely and also has been proven to be an antidifference of tan(x):

$$f_2(x)=-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left( \psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+1-x\right)+\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+x\right) \right. $$
$$ \qquad \left. -\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}+1\right)-\psi \left(k \pi -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)+C$$

This function has a fancy graphic (see the initial discussion).
Since it is known that a function can have several antidifferences which differ between each other by a 1-periodic function, it is interesting, whether the both functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are equal or what is the difference between them (of course if the first function actually can be evaluated numerically).

Comment: I think the question is: Can anyone provide a definition for $f_1$, since the conventional one does not work for subscripts like $q=e^{2i}$ where $|q| \ge 1$.  Without a definition, there no way to say whether it is equal to $f_2$.